# Software Recommendations

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'd like to suggest something in relation to this (and other) question(s):  [Best platform for collaborative worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/best-platform-for-collaborative-worldbuilding)

On the Software Recommendations SE this is the "what makes a good question" entry on [help](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features Please read our question
>     quality guidelines.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> If you're asking for alternatives, be sure to describe the features
>   you're using and why what you have isn't up for the task.
>
> On the topic of answers, we request that answers demonstrate how the
>   recommended product meets the requirement and is suitable for the
>   intended purpose. Please read our answer quality guidelines for more
>   information.

Simply put I suggest we adopt the same rules on software recommendations.

Comment: Sounds sensible to me :)

Comment: OS probably needs adding, no point in getting suggestions for a Mac if the user users a PC!

Comment: @Liath Skipping all the grognard definition dweebery that my knee jerked with when I read that... That is less of an issue in this web3.0 world.

Comment: @Liath I feel like that falls under requirements but if we want to spell it out we can.  Does this warrant addition to the help/tour page?

Answer (score 2):

I think that software recommendations are fine for Worldbuilding, because humans can't do everything by themselves. [Simulating weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/tool-to-simulate-climate-weather-effects), for example, is a task that needs software. The [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag has done well so far, though only 11 questions use it.

On to the guidelines. I think that they're pretty good for us. We probably should change one thing, though:

> Requests for world building software recommendations should choose a specific task. Some questions can be too broad, such as asking for the best software for doing a certain task.

We may also want to discuss the generality of "doing a certain task" in a meta post - in other words, how general [software-recommendation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) questions can be.

We should also include a link to the [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag.